# How to apply textures without them mirroring?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, mirror

I have a person I modeled using the mirror modifier, and now whenever I apply a texture it mirrors the texture as well. How do I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without physical geometry on the other side of the bilateral axis there isn't much to do here. Apply the mirror modifier and then you can set up texture that is on one side only.

Comment: Ok I applied the mirror and it still does not work, it still mirrors the texture

Comment: Did you **UV unwrap again** after you changed the mesh shape by applying the mirror? Because otherwise, it can only use the half UV space from before...

Answer (score 0):

If you've finished modelling can you just click apply to the mirror modifier which will then just give you a single mesh to work with?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Ok I applied the mirror and it still does not work, it still mirrors the texture

Comment: Did you **UV unwrap again** after you changed the mesh shape by applying the mirror? Because otherwise, it can only use the half UV space from before...

Answer (score 0):

For applying the texture first you have to UV unwrap the 3d model. When you unwrap the model before applying the mirror modifier, there is no geometry on the other side. So if you use this UV map, then the texture will be flipped. If you unwrap the model after applying the mirror modifier then the geometry on the other side will be unwrapped too. Remember if you have unwrapped the model before applying and did not unwrap after applying the mirror modifier then the texture will still be flipped. You have to unwrap after applying the mirror modifier.